# C# .NET - Difference between SendKeys, SendInput, SendMessage, InputInjector and Cursor.Position

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I am learning and building my first UWP test app, and need a way to simulate:

- relative mouse movement
- absolute mouse positioning
- keyboard typing (not necessarily key presses/releases)
- fine tuned x&y scrolling (so I can scroll by any amount)

I have come across the following methods for doing this, but can't figure out which ones are modern / best for UWP apps or best in general for my purposes:

- `SendKeys` (A C# wrapper for `SendInput` of some sort?)
- `SendInput` (A win32 API for simulating events, but is it best for UWP?)
- `SendMessage` (Used for directly typing into focused applications?)
- `InputInjector` (A more modern but limited way of simulating inputs, can't absolutely position cursor?)
- `Cursor.Position` (A function for cursor movement and positing)

There are so many methods and approaches to this problem, and I'm not entirely sure which of these is most supported or recommended for UWP apps, or yields the best results.

The purpose of this project is to be able to control my PC (move the mouse, type), by interacting with through my phone. For example my phone becomes a trackpad, or I can type in my phone's soft keyboard and it types into my PC. The PC hosts a server on the local network, and the phone send input data packets to this server. The server receives these input data packets, and executes them (which is where I need the ability to simulate keyboard/mouse events). Very similar to [Remote Mouse](https://www.remotemouse.net/).

So my questions are:

- What are the differences between these methods? (Like Windows Forms or Win32??)
- Which is best for UWP apps / my need here?
- Are there any better (not listed) solutions?

This is my first look into this stuff (C#, .NET, Windows dev) so any and all information is very helpful.

Thanks for your help!
Dan :D

*Edit*

Further research has shown that [`InputInjector`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.preview.injection.inputinjector) is under the UWP reference, [`SendKeys`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send) and [`Cursor.Position`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.cursor.position) are both under the .NET reference. Does this mean that `InputInjector` is the most ideal?

Comment: whats your end goal in this? what are you trying to achieve when simulating the mouse?

Comment: @sommmen Just edited to clarify, but essentially to execute input commands that it receives from a phone across a local network.

Comment: Do you want the application itself to be programmable, or do you want to make a version of teamviewer? maybe explain one use-case/user story for what you want, because i think it matters a lot in what route you'd like to take. Also i've used AutoIT before for windows automation and i believe it has dlls aswell so you can integrate that in a .NET app aswell https://www.autoitscript.com/site/

Comment: @sommmen Just edited again. It looks to be along a similar vein to teamviewer, but more specialised to certain situations: Its only on the same local network, its only phone to pc, and the phone "turns into" external input devices (eg drag on your phone screen like a trackpad to move the mouse on the PC similarly). So closer to [Remote Mouse](https://www.remotemouse.net/).

Comment: @HansPassant Cheers for the answer! You've linked to a repo which looks to be for testing, which isn't what the purpose of my application is. Does this mean that there really isn't *any* proper way to simulate input events in a UWP app? If so, then is it worth switching to Win32 or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After researching some more, I found that [`InjectedInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.preview.injection) is the only one included in the UWP API.

To clarify, when developing a Windows application, in Visual Studio you must select one "type" to use, be it WPF, Windows Forms, Win32 or UWP. UWP is the only one (mostly) that can be uploaded to the Microsoft Store.

This meant that I could only use methods inside the UWP API, in this case WinRT was a part of UWP and `InjectedInput` is a part of WinRT.

It supports absolute mouse positioning with the `"Absolute"` option, relative mouse movement with the `"Move"` option, and scrolling with the `"Wheel"` and `"HWheel"` options used in [`InjectedInputMouseOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.preview.injection.injectedinputmouseoptions) alongside [`InjectedInputMouseInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.preview.injection.injectedinputmouseinfo). Keyboard input can be done with [`InjectedInputKeyOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.preview.injection.injectedinputkeyoptions) alongside [`InjectedInputKeyboardInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.preview.injection.injectedinputkeyboardinfo).

Use the `"Option"` variant class to modify the effect of the input (such as selecting which options to change), and then use [`InputInjector`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.preview.injection.inputinjector) with its `TryCreate()` method to instantiate it, along with the relevant `InjectMouseInput` or `InjectKeyboardInput` to execute the input injection.

[This](https://github.com/MartinZikmund/blog-2018/tree/master/InjectedMouse) sample code alongside its related [blog post](https://blog.mzikmund.com/2018/01/injecting-input-in-uwp-apps/) is fantastic for understanding the basic useage, it jumps straight to the chase.